# What to use to represent a lambda character in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, character

In the program, Lambda λ theoretically represents nothing: ''.  I thought of representing this programatically as '\0', but obviously that terminates a string which is not necessarily what lambda does.  Also, I am reading in from `istringstream` and it has problems reading that character in.

So what character would you use?

Comment: Do you need a way to write and read a literal lambda character or are you lookingmfor a way to serialize/deserialize an empty value?

Comment: It's basically a directed graph with strings in the format `IntCharInt`, e.g. "0y1", "1λ2", "2o3" = yo.  Then I dissect that with istringstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a reason for representing Int,Char,Int as a string, rather than just define a struct to hold the data.

As you say, `\0` doesn't work as it terminates the string. But there are other invisible ASCII characters that you can use and easily escape in C++. Have a look at [this list of escape codes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).